# SQL JOIN in Redis(FT module or other solutions)

Tags: redis, ft.search

I want to transfer part of the **SQL** queries to **redis** and ran into a problem that redis does not have an analogue of the `JOIN` functionality

Example in SQL.
Got 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `games` (
    `id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `fname` CHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE `log` (
    `id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `fgame_id` CHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
    `finfo` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL
    ...
);
```

Wonna get game name by game id:

```
SELECT log.fgame_id, games.fname, log.finfo
FROM log
LEFT JOIN games ON games.id = log.fgame_id
```

In Redis i created index with the same names and similar structure:

```
FT.CREATE games
  ON HASH
    PREFIX 1 "games:"
  SCHEMA
    id        TAG SORTABLE
    fname     TEXT SORTABLE


FT.CREATE log
  ON HASH
    PREFIX 1 "log:"
  SCHEMA
    id        TAG SORTABLE
    fgame_id  TEXT SORTABLE
    finfo     TEXT NOINDEX
```

Is it possible to implement **SQL** `JOIN` method on **REDIS**(FT.SEARCH/FT.AGGREGATE)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't support to JOIN straight from Redis using Search. Following your example you can use 2x different PREFIX to map different data tables (games: and log:). For example:

```
FT.CREATE idx ON HASH PREFIX 2 "games:" "log:" SCHEMA "id" as id TAG "text" as text TEXT "price" as price NUMERIC
```

and adding the data using the shared key:

```
HSET games:1 id 1000 text IndianaJones
HSET games:2 id 2000 text Starwars

HSET log:1 id 1000 price 199
HSET log:2 id 2000 price 399
```

finally using FT.AGGREGATE to return the joint table, like in:

```
FT.AGGREGATE idx "@id:{1000}" LOAD 2 @text @price
1) "1"
2) 1) "text"
   2) "IndianaJones"
3) 1) "price"
   2) "199"
```

hope that help as a workaround :-)